# Jacobi Operator for Minimal (or Extremal) Surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

**Setup:** Consider a space (or spacetime, the signature doesn't matter) $(M,g_{ab})$ of arbitrary dimension, and let $\Sigma_\lambda$ be a one-parameter (with parameter $\lambda$) family of surfaces of arbitrary dimension embedded in $(M,g_{ab})$.  Let $h_{ab}$ denote the induced metric on the $\Sigma_\lambda$ (I assume this metric is nondegenerate, i.e. that the $\Sigma_\lambda$ are not null); then the extrinsic curvature of the $\Sigma_\lambda$ is given by
$$
K^a_{bc} = {h_b}^d {h_c}^e \nabla_d {h_e}^a,
$$
where $\nabla_a$ is the covariant derivative compatible with $g_{ab}$.  The mean curvature is $K^a = h^{bc} K^a_{bc}$.

Define $\eta^a \equiv (\partial_\lambda)^a$ (so that $\eta^a$ is the "deviation vector field between infinitesimally nearby surfaces"); we may without loss of generality take $\eta^a$ to be normal to the $\Sigma_\lambda$ since any component of $\eta^a$ tangential to the surfaces just generates some diffeomorphism, which is uninteresting.

**Goal:** I want an elliptic equation for $\eta^a$ on the $\Sigma_\lambda$.  Ultimately I'm interested in the case where the $\Sigma_\lambda$ are all minimal (more generally, extremal) surfaces.

**Issue:** I have been able to obtain such an equation, which I'm pretty sure is correct (see Method 1 below).  However, this equation disagrees by an annoying factor of two with the equation I expect I should get from the second variation formula for minimal surfaces (Method 2 below).  I'm asking if someone understand the reason for this discrepancy (did I screw something up?  Is a step I've made incorrect?)

**Method 1:** By my own work, I can show that $\eta^a$ should satisfy the equation
$$
{P^a}_b \Delta_\Sigma \eta^b + 2{S^a}_b \eta^b + R_{bcde} h^{bd} \eta^c P^{ea} - {P^a}_c \eta^b \nabla_b K^c = 0,
$$
where $P_{ab} \equiv g_{ab} - h_{ab}$ is the projector onto the subspace orthogonal to the $\Sigma_\lambda$, ${P^a}_b \Delta_\Sigma \eta^b \equiv {P^a}_b h^{cd} \nabla_c({h_d}^e \nabla_e \eta^b)$ is the Laplacian on the normal bundle, $S^{ab} \equiv K^a_{cd} K^b_{ef} g^{ce} g^{df}$ is Simons' operator,  and $R_{abcd}$ is the Riemann tensor of $g_{ab}$ (defined via $(\nabla_a \nabla_b - \nabla_b \nabla_a)u_c = {R_{abc}}^du_d$).  It took me about two pages of work to derive this equation, so instead of writing it all up here let me instead provide a check of this equation (though I can provide the details if someone wishes).  Consider the case where the $\Sigma_\lambda$ are codimension-one and normal to a geodesic congruence with unit normal vector field $\eta^a$.  Then $h_{ab} = g_{ab} - \epsilon \eta_a \eta_b$, where $\epsilon = \eta^2 = \pm 1$ (depending on the signature of $\eta^a$).  One can show that $\nabla_a \eta_b = -\eta_c K^c_{ab}$, and thus the expansion and shear of this congruence are $\theta = -\eta_a K^a$ and $\sigma_{ab} = -\eta_c K^c_{ab} - \theta h_{ab}/(d-1)$ (with $d$ the dimension of $M$).  Contracting the above equation with $\eta_d$, it is then easy enough to show that one obtains
$$
\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda} = -\frac{1}{d-1} \theta^2 - \sigma_{ab} \sigma^{ab} - R_{ab} \eta^a \eta^b,
$$
where $R_{ab}$ is the Ricci tensor of $g_{ab}$.  This is precisely the Raychaudhuri equation (with vanishing twist $\omega_{ab}$, as must be the case since by construction the geodesic congruence here is hypersurface orthogonal), which verifies that at least in this case the equation I derived is correct.  (Even more explicitly, you can check the equation for e.g. concentric spheres in flat Euclidean space).

Note that in the particular case that the $\Sigma_\lambda$ are all taken to be minimal (or extremal), we have that $K^a = 0$, and thus
$$
{P^a}_b \Delta_\Sigma \eta^b + 2{S^a}_b \eta^b + R_{bcde} h^{bd} \eta^c P^{ea} = 0.
$$

**Method 2:** Denote the areas of the $\Sigma_\lambda$ by $A(\lambda) = \int_{\Sigma_\lambda} \epsilon_\lambda$, where $\epsilon_\lambda$ is the natural volume form on $\Sigma_\lambda$ (also assume the $\Sigma_\lambda$ are compact).  From e.g. Colding and Minicozzi's book "A Course in Minimal Surfaces", chapter 1 section 8, if $\Sigma_0$ is a minimal surface, we have that
$$
\frac{d^2 A(0)}{d\lambda^2} = -\int_{\Sigma_0} \eta_a L\eta^a |_{\lambda = 0},
$$
where the Jacobi operator $L$ has the form
$$
L \eta^a = {P^a}_b \Delta_\Sigma \eta^b + {S^a}_b \eta^b + R_{bcde} h^{bd} \eta^c P^{ea}
$$
(I had to convert from math notation to my physics notation here, but I think this expression is the same as Colding and Minicozzi's).  Now, if *all* the $\Sigma_\lambda$ are minimal, then we must have $d^2 A(\lambda)/d\lambda^2 = 0$, and thus we should have that on every $\Sigma_\lambda$,
$$
L\eta^a = {P^a}_b \Delta_\Sigma \eta^b + {S^a}_b \eta^b + R_{bcde} h^{bd} \eta^c P^{ea} = 0.
$$
Note the issue here: this formula looks almost identical to the one I derived above, except for a factor of two discrepancy in the coefficient of Simons' operator.  My formula *must* have that factor of two, otherwise it wouldn't reproduce the Raychaudhuri equation.  However, the second variation formula from Colding and Minicozzi is well-established, and it seems to me like it ought to reproduce the same equation for $\eta^a$ on each $\Sigma_\lambda$.  What's going on?